# Basis object appearing

Tags: xact

I want to calculate explicitly an expression involving covariant derivatives of a Riemann tensor. However, in the output I get Basis with indices generated, which I am not sure how to get rid off and why it is appearing that way. Here is the setup:

```
DefManifold[H, 4, {a, b, c, d, a1, a2, a3, a4, b1, b2, b3, b4, f, j}];

DefMetric[-1, g[-a, -b], CD, {";", "\[EmptyDownTriangle]"}];

DefChart[RW, H, {0, 1, 2, 3}, {t[], r[], \[Theta][], \[Phi][]}];

MetricInBasis[g, -RW, metric];

ChangeComponents[RiemannCD[{a, RW}, {b, RW}, {c, RW}, {d, RW}], RiemannCD[-{a, RW}, -{b, RW}, -{c, RW}, -{d, RW}]];
```

Note that `metric` is a defined expression in my code - I omitted it due its length. Then, I wish to compute:

```
-CD[-a][CD[-b][RiemannCD[-c, -a2, a1, b1] RiemannCD[-a1, -b1, c, a2]]] // ToBasis[RW]
```

And the output is:

```
- xAct`xTensor`Basis[{-b, -RW}, b1]RiemannCD[{-a4, -RW}, {-a2, -RW}, {a1, RW}, {a3, RW}](CD[{-a, -RW}][CD[-b1][RiemannCD[{-a1, -RW}, {-a3, -RW}, {a4, RW}, {a2, RW}]]]) xAct`xTensor`Basis[{-b, -RW}, b1]RiemannCD[{-a1, -RW}, {-a3, -RW}, {a4, RW}, {a2, RW}](CD[{-a, -RW}][CD[-b1][RiemannCD[{-a4, -RW}, {-a2, -RW}, {a1, RW}, {a3, RW}]]]) -(CD[{-a, -RW}][RiemannCD[{-a4, -RW}, {-a2, -RW}, {a1, RW}, {a3, RW}]])(CD[{-b, -RW}][RiemannCD[{-a1, -RW}, {-a3, -RW}, {a4, RW}, {a2, RW}]]) - (CD[{-a, -RW}][RiemannCD[{-a1, -RW}, {-a3, -RW}, {a4, RW}, {a2, RW}]]) (CD[{-b, -RW}][RiemannCD[{-a4, -RW}, {-a2, -RW}, {a1, RW}, {a3, RW}]])
```

I am confused why there is Basis appearing. I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: This seems quite specific to xAct, rather than to mathematica. Have you tried the [xAct user group](https://groups.google.com/g/xact)?

Comment: Thank for your comment, I wasn't aware of it but I will try - thanks!